# pandas: extract every 10 rows based on a column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame and I only want to keep rows that `time = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ... (every 0.1 second)`

[image]

I tried to use the floor function like below, but it doesn't work with pandas:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: This is not the way to ask a pandas question. First of all we [cannot copy & paste](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) you picture. Second, include a small example dataset and based on that example dataset an expected output. So we can visually see what you try to do. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: `big_frame.time` refers to the column if i’m correct

Comment: @Axium Yes. big_frame.time is a column

Answer (score 1):

What I will do

```
big_frame[big_frame.time.mul(100)%10==0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by doing the following trick:

```
import sys
epsilon = sys.float_info.epsilon
big_frame[(big_frame.time + epsilon)%0.1 < 0.005]
```